# Need help regarding integrating android functions with premade views

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm just new to android and java and i m trying to build a sample android application.
I picked up application view from androhive looks like google+ app
and made my function following to many tutorials online
but i'm unable to integrate them.
here are my codes
Here is my fragment sample which is used in switching activity using sidebar

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MHEFragment extends Fragment {

    public MHEFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Heres my function os listview

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
 private String jsonResult;
 private String url = "http://192.168.129.1/1.php";
 private ListView listView;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  accessWebService();
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 // Async Task to access the web
 private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
   try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
      response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
   }

   catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
  }

  private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
   String rLine = "";
   StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
   BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

   try {
    while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
     answer.append(rLine);
    }
   }

   catch (IOException e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   return answer;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   ListDrwaer();
  }
 }// end async task

 public void accessWebService() {
  JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
  // passes values for the urls string array
  task.execute(new String[] { url });
 }

 // build hash set for list view
 public void ListDrwaer() {
  List<Map<String, String>> storyList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

  try {
   JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
   JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("story");

   for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonChildNode.optString("story_name");
    String number = jsonChildNode.getString("story_id").toString();
    String outPut = number + "-" + name;


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View name, int position,
                long number) {
             Intent intnt = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Tester.class);  
             String deta = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            String myStr = deta.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" );
             intnt.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,myStr);
             startActivity(intnt);

        }
     });
    storyList.add(createStory("stories", outPut));
   }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, storyList,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    new String[] { "stories" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
  listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);



 }

 private HashMap<String, String> createStory(String name, String number) {
  HashMap<String, String> storyNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
  storyNameNo.put(name, number);
  return storyNameNo;
 }
}
```

How can i integrate my listview in above fragment?

Comment: where is your list view in your fragment?

Answer (score 0):

If you want ListView in fragment then you'd be better off using your Fragment which would subclass ListFragment.
And the onCreateView() from ListFragment will return a ListView that you can populate.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listfragments

For Fragments, if you want a separate ListView and more in one fragment, it'l help if you go through:
http://www.easyinfogeek.com/2013/07/full-example-of-using-fragment-in.html
..for what is more to the layout and calling onCreateView()

Also, (not a part of the question, but from & for your code) if it helps, i'd suggest

Use a for each loop where you can instead of for(;;)
(in your case at: for each json child node in json main node)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

[How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)